# How to pass image to a 2D array using Matlab MEX

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, mex

I want to read some image to run a C++ MEX function to process this image. The image is originally stored as a Matlab 3D matrix, and then converted to a 2D matrix and each slice of the image is stored as a 1D vector. Here is some example codes below.

First: the MEX function:

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {

unsigned int** ubuff;

size_t col_ubuff    = mxGetN(prhs[0]);
size_t row_ubuff    = mxGetM(prhs[0]);

ubuff               = (unsigned int **)mxCalloc(col_ubuff, row_ubuff);

for(int x = 0; x < col_ubuff; x++) {
    ubuff[x] = (unsigned int *) mxCalloc(row_ubuff, sizeof(unsigned int));
}

for (int col=0; col < col_ubuff; col++) {
    for (int row=0; row < row_ubuff; row++) {
        ubuff[col][row] = mxGetPr(prhs[0])[row+col*row_ubuff];
    }
}

unsigned int the_pixel_i_want = ubuff[16][2*32 + 2];
printf ("Debug: %d\n\n", the_pixel_i_want);

return;
}
```

Second: The program can be compiled; however, the results of running the program is strange; for example, I have some test codes and test image with all pixels to be 188,

```
%% Test input image as 2D array
clc; clf; clear all; close all;

volImage                                = 188.*ones(32,32,32);
volImageVec                             = reshape(volImage, 32*32, 32)';
volImageVec                             = uint32(volImageVec);

TestInputImage(volImageVec');`
```

But the output sometimes be 188 and sometimes be 0. Is there a memory leak somewhere in my code? Thanks very much for your help.

edit:

Thanks for editing. I found a way from other people. Just put it here for other people's interest.

1) The line

```
ubuff = (unsigned int **)mxCalloc(col_ubuff, row_ubuff);
```

should be

```
ubuff = (unsigned int **)mxCalloc(col_ubuff, sizeof(unsigned int *));
```

2) The line

```
 ubuff[col][row] = mxGetPr(prhs[0])[row+col*row_ubuff];
```

should be

```
 ubuff[col][row] = ((unsigned int *)mxGetData(prhs[0]))[row+col*row_ubuff];
```

Comment: Thanks for editing. I found a way from other people. Just put it here for other people's interest.

Comment: Better to post your answer as an answer rather than an extension to your question.  SO is entirely cool with this.  Then, after a decent interval, you can accept your own answer. By posting an answer the grazers among us can see, immediately, that the question has been answered and drag our sorry rep-whoring asses off to the next unanswered question.